# R: Unite multiple segments() and points() in base R plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, points, segments

I am plotting several graphs defined by ID into different files in the following way.

```
xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME3","NAME3"),ID=c(87,87,87,199,199,199,233,233), X_START_YEAR=c(1950,1988,1994,1899,1909,1924,1945,1948),Y_START_VALUE=c(75,25,-90,-8,-55,-10,-9,12),X_END_YEAR=c(1985,1994,1999,1904,1924,1987,1946,1949), Y_END_VALUE=c(20,50,-15,-70,-80,-100,24,59))

  NAME  ID X_START_YEAR Y_START_VALUE X_END_YEAR Y_END_VALUE
1 NAME1  87         1950            75       1985          20
2 NAME1  87         1988            25       1994          50
3 NAME1  87         1994           -90       1999         -15
4 NAME2 199         1899            -8       1904         -70
5 NAME2 199         1909           -55       1924         -80
6 NAME2 199         1924           -10       1987        -100
7 NAME3 233         1945            -9       1946          24
8 NAME3 233         1948            12       1949          59

# Split glacier names by ID
ind <- split(x = xy,f = xy[,'ID'])

# Plot
for (i in ind){
  xx = unlist(i[,grep('X_',colnames(i))])
  yy = unlist(i[,grep('Y_',colnames(i))])    
  filename <- paste0(i[1, 'ID'], '.png') 
  png(filename, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
  if(any(xx < 1946)) {my_x_lim <- c(min(xx), 2014)} else {my_x_lim <- c(1946, 2014)} 
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(xx, yy)
  i <- i[,-1]
  segments(i[,2],i[,3],i[,4],i[,5],lwd=2)
  points(xx, yy, pch=21,cex=1, bg='white') 
  dev.off()
}
```

**My question:** What I am looking for is a base R solution to include the whole data of `xy` into one plot (instead of several plots like the code above does) and have multiple lines and points (groups defined by ID) in a legend. I figured out a quite straightforward way to do this with `ggplot` but I am interested how to do that in base R. Any ideas?

Here is the `ggplot` code that might give you an idea of what I am attempting to do:

```
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(xy)
p = p + geom_segment(aes(x = X_START_YEAR, xend = X_END_YEAR, y = Y_START_VALUE, yend = Y_END_VALUE,linetype=NAME))
print(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
noms<-levels(xy$NAME)
nblev<-nlevels(xy$NAME)
linetype<-(1:9)[1:nblev]

par(mar=c(5,4,4,10),xpd=TRUE)
plot(c(xy[,3],xy[,5]),c(xy[,4],xy[,6]),type="p",pch=21,xlab="YEAR",ylab="VALUE",las=1)
segments(xy[,3],xy[,4],xy[,5],xy[,6],lty=linetype[as.numeric(xy$NAME)])
coord<-par("usr")
legend(coord[2]+10,sum(coord[3:4])/2,lty=linetype,legend=noms,bty="n")
```

Comment: thank you @CathG. The only thing that I am still struggling with is with the legend that it automatically takes every `NAME` from `xy` and not only pastes it in. Is there a way that I don't need to paste it in manually?

Comment: For example if I have my data grouped by different NAMES which have the title Example 1 and then next group Test and then Example 3 and so on. So that I don't have to paste this in manually.

Comment: maybe with levels(xy$NAME)